# Date values displayed as numbers instead of dates

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010

Whenever I type a date into one of my worksheets the cell displays the value as a number not a date.

The cell's value is a date and the format is date but the text displayed is a number.

```
? activecell.Value
8/5/2015 8:01:46 AM 
? activecell.NumberFormat
m/d/yyyy
? activecell.Text
42221.3345601852
```

I would like it to display the value in date format.  Some Googling around showed that I should uncheck the "formula" box in Tools, Options, View. https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/241072.

However in Excel 2010 there is no "Tools" menu.

Comment: Excel 2010 - Press CTRL + ` (grave accent) - toggles formula display [Display or hide formulas](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Display-or-hide-formulas-f7f5ab4e-bf24-4efc-8fc9-0c1b77a5356f)

Comment: Works! post it as an answer

Comment: Done  and dusted ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### I should uncheck the "formula" box in Tools > Options > View

> but there is no "Tools" menu

In Excel 2010 you can press <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>`</kbd> (grave accent) to toggle the display of formulas.

---

#### Display or hide formulas

> You can control the display of formulas in the following ways:
>
> 1. Switch between displaying formulas and formula results on a worksheet    This method is a toggle between two different display
>      modes. It does not change the state of the cells.
> 2. Prevent formulas from displaying in the formula bar by protecting the cells that contain them    This method changes the
>      state of the cells – protected cells cannot be edited.
> 3. Show hidden formulas by removing the protection from cells    This method changes the state of the cells – unprotected cells can be
>      edited. Make sure this is an acceptable risk, and make a backup copy
>      of the workbook before you proceed.
>
> **Switch between displaying formulas and their values on a worksheet**
>
> Press <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>`</kbd> (grave accent)

Source [Display or hide formulas](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Display-or-hide-formulas-f7f5ab4e-bf24-4efc-8fc9-0c1b77a5356f)